# How to detect when "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little application on web that uses JS Alerts. I am planning to use modal pops later, but for the time being, does anyone know how to detect if the user clicked on the "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" and then fire some js function?

Comment: Is that a standard checkbox, or specific to a browser? If so, I would doubt there would be a generic solution

Comment: There isn't (it's a browser convenience for the user, not anything in-spec on the javascript side). But why not stop using JS alerts instead? Much better to use a custom dialog and have your code wait/trigger on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed possible to detect if prevent additional dialogs has been clicked by working with javascript date
you can try this lines of code

```js
window.nativeAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(message) {
  var timeBeforeAlert = new Date();
  var confirmIfBlocked = nativeAlert(message);  
  var timeAfterAlert = new Date();
  if ((timeAfterAlert - timeBeforeAlert) < 400) {
    tellTheUserDialog("you can use a Div to tell the user he has blocked alert");
  }
}
```

if users does not see alert then timeAfterAlert will be almost the same as timeBeforeAlert, i used 400 milliseconds just for reference you can come up with yours

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect it because it is a browser feature which helps the user get rid of indefinite popups. This is particularly useful when your JavaScript code shows popups in a loop.

A good idea is to use modals or plugins like [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) to show alerts.